Elimination of variance
My load cells output is transmitted via amplifiers in 4-20 format and before PLC it shows 4 at no load status but my PLC vendors says he receives continous variation in counts which upsets his load calculations for tare weight.
He blames the amplifiers for not giving a steady input and amplifier says 4 amp at zero is what he is supposed to give and he is delivering that.
Alternate vendors have suggested to abandon 4-20 and go in for RS 485 by modifying amplifiers and putting a card before PLC to accept RS485 instead of 4-20.
What would be the right way to analyse the issue? and find a solution?

It appears that you are attempting to measure something finer than the resolution supported by the load cell.  What is the resolution supported by the load cell and what is the amount of noise at no load that is disturbing the tare ?
